# How to get value at the ng-model under ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind

```
<div class="check">
<label><span ng-repeat="prod in products">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="prod.cid"  value="" ng-change="OnCheck()">
{{prod.c}}</br></br>{{prod.cid}}</br>
</span>
</div>
```

In the above html file i got checkboxes dynamically  from control of  function `a()` .now i need to get the binding values of that check boxes in control of function `OnCheck()` .How can i get the values the of binding values in another function name like `OnCheck()` which is also in the same control .And I have the other check boxes which are not dynamically ,I am using `OnCheck()` ng-change for all the check boxes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
   <div class="check">
    <label><span ng-repeat="prod in products">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="prod.cid"  value="" ng-change="OnCheck(prod)">
    {{prod.c}}</br></br>{{prod.cid}}</br>
    </span>
    </div>
```

js:

```
...
$scope.OnCheck = function(product)
```

// you can have access via product
    ...

or

HTML:

```
   <div class="check">
    <label><span ng-repeat="prod in products">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="prod.cid"  value="" ng-change="OnCheck(prod.cid)">
    {{prod.c}}</br></br>{{prod.cid}}</br>
    </span>
    </div>
```

js

```
    $scope.OnCheck = function(cid)
// in this case you can have access to prod.cid only
    ...
```

Comment: But i have remaining check boxes which are not dynamically in html page aslo use the OnCheck() method .How can i deal all the check boxes actions into one function.

Comment: can you please update your question to show how exactly that look ?

Comment: how can i got all the cids of check boxes for your first answer

Comment: For your first answer it shows Object in alert and true in console ,but not the actual value .The Object structure is  {cid=true, cat="B", $$hashKey="00A"},how can i get actual value

Comment: value of what cid ? product.cid

Comment: It is integer ,i have 1,2,3,4 values in the object

Comment: ,my object structure like [{"cid":1,"c":"B"},{"cid":2,"c":"C"},{"cid":3,"c":"I"},{"cid":4,"c":"P"}] and i got  4 check boxes

Comment: thank you u know the problem ,i need cid values 1,2,3,4 at controller

Comment: to get all values you need to iterate your products array http://jsbin.com/lixoz/3/edit?html,console

Answer (score 0):

For Dynamically created check boxes,

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="prod.cid" ng-change="OnCheck(prod.cid)">
```

For check boxes not created dynamically,

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="OnCheck('value')">
          //Give the value of checkbox between the quotes ''.
```

In JS,

```
$scope.OnCheck = function(Value){
   console.log(Value);
}
```

Comment: For your  answer it shows Object in alert and true in console ,but not the actual value .The Object structure is {cid=true, cat="B", $$hashKey="00A"}.How can i get actual value